# Match nested brackets with JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to write a JavaScript RegEx which returns content(maybe including nested parentheses) which is between parentheses like the solution described in this [article](http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/match-nested-brackets-with-regex-new.html) (implemented by Java RegEx)

String:

```
xxx
@connect(({ app }) => (
  {
    ...app
  }
))
xxx
```

Result:

```
({ app }) => (
  {
    ...app
  }
)
```

Is it possible to resolve it with JavaScript RegEx?

Comment: So, what have you tried till now? Where are you stuck, what is the regex you are currently using? Currently you have a 'yes'/'no' question (is it possible ...)

Comment: Is this for an infinite depth of nested `( )`

Comment: @Icepickle The solution in http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/match-nested-brackets-with-regex-new.html implemented with Java RegEx, not applicable to JavaScript. So  I ask 'Is it possible...'

Comment: @JGNI Just for finite depth :-)

Comment: It's not possible. JavaScript does not support forward references in the way Java/PCRE do.

Comment: @wp78de Yes, mentioned in that article

Comment: Exactly. So, what's the point of this question if you already knew? If so, you should have pointed that out. Or haven't you read the entire article before you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:

```
/                     // start expression
  (?<=@connect\()     // positive lookbehind
  \(                  // open parenthesis
  (.|[\n\r])+         // anything, including new-lines
  \)                  // closed parenthesis
  (?=\)$)             // positive lookahead
/gm                   // global match, multiline
```

```js
var re = /(?<=@connect\()\((.|[\n\r])+\)(?=\)$)/gm;
var s = `xxx
@connect(({ app }) => (
  {
    ...app
  }
))
xxx`

console.log(s.match(re)[0]);
```